# Java :- How to save in Microsoft Excel 2010 when read through csv

Tags: java, excel, csv

I am able to read the csv file in Microsoft excel, but when I try to save it, it gets saved as text as it's in tab delimited form and the changes made are lost.

```
WebUtils.download(response, datafetcher, form.getString("reportName") + ".xls",
                "application/vnd.excel", hdr, "\t");
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are in excel, then use the "Save As" menu option and choose the desired format.

Comment: i know we can choose the save as option but my client doesn't want to do an extra step. She said she lost some changes when she hit 'Save'.

Comment: i surfed and found out jasper report can also be the solution..but for that i need to re write my report all over again...so was looking for any quick solution.

Comment: It soulds like your client is a goofball.  Excel warns the user when they are saving in a format that will not support changes that they have made.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you are relying on the fact that Excel will go ahead and load a CSV file that is called something.XLS, but when it's saved again it will maintain the CSV format and therefore lose all the formatting applied. As DwB says, Excel should warn about this with a fairly clear message unless that's been disabled.

I don't think there's a lot you can do here, other than some client education or rewriting your report to actually export a genuine XLS or XLSX file.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. But my client doesn't want to do clicking  and  go for warnings every time she opens. So i implemented my report using Jasper and it opens for her in native excel and now she can save without warnings and clicks :)